# Regex to grab email address in a forwarded message

Tags: ruby, regex, email

I'm trying to use regex to grab the email address in a forwarded message.  Something like this:

```
test_string = '"---------- Forwarded message ----------\\r\\nFrom: <test@email.com>\\r\\nDate: Sun, Feb 2, 201\"'
```

I'd like to be able to extract "test@email.com" or "From: ".  So far I've tried:

```
test_string.scan(/From:<(.*)>/)
```

And it doesn't find the email address.  Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do that. Just don't. A regex that simple isn't nearly sophisticated to accurately catch real email addresses. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1, which is about validation, but will give you a good idea what you really need, and how difficult it is to do correctly.

Comment: Not trying to validate, just trying to extract emails. I'm okay if some emails fall through the typical regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the space between `From:` and `<(.*)>`

Comment: Maybe try `/From:\s*<(.*?)>/`.